# When loadNibName used in init, ViewController can't recieve viewDidLoad event

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When I call `loadNibNamed:` in `init`, the `UIViewController` can't receive `viewDidLoad` event.
But if I put call to `loadNibNamed:` somewhere else, it works fine. What is the reason?

```
-(id)init
{
   self=[super init];

   if(self){
       [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MainView" owner:self options:nil]; 
   }
   return  self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you are writing implementation of init , you are not calling super with nib name correctly.

```
-(id)init {
 self = [super initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil]; 
return  self;
}
```